# Capture check_output value

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to capture the return value of check_output instead of having it automatically print to the command line. Unfortunately, my solution is not working and I'm not sure why. I've included my code and it's output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from multiprocessing import Pool
from subprocess import check_output,CalledProcessError


def job(cmd):

    result = ""
    try:
        result = check_output(cmd.split())  # Split string into list.
        print("job result length = {0}".format(len(result)), file=sys.stdout)
    except CalledProcessError as error:
        raise Exception("Exit status of the child process: {0}\
            Command used to spawn child process: {1}\
            Output of the child process: {2}".format(error.returncode,error.cmd,error.output))


def main():

    # Sets up a process pool. Defaults to number of cores.
    # Each input gets passed to job and processed in a separate process.
    p = Pool()
    result = []
    try:
        # cmd_list is just a list of system commands which have been verified to work.
        result = list(p.imap_unordered(job, cmd_list))
        print("main result length = {0}".format(len(result)), file=sys.stdout)
        print("{0}".format(result), file=sys.stdout)
    except Exception as error:
        print("Error: {0}. Aborting...".format(error), file=sys.stderr)
        p.close()
        p.terminate()
    else:
        p.close()
        p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output**

In addition to the output of each command executed by check_output, my print statements reveal some unexpected results:

```
job result length = 0
job result length = 0
main result length = 2
[None, None]
```

I would expect job result length to equal 2 and result to contain the return values of the child processes.

Comment: Why are you raising a generic exception on top?

Comment: @Zizouz212 ...my intention was to report a more customized error message.

Comment: If you catch that somewhere, it would be harder to figure out what it is or where it came from. You could create your own exception in two lines too.

Answer (score 1):

`result` is a local variable. Either return it:

```
def job(cmd):
    # something goes here
    return result
```

Or make it global:

```
result = ""
def job(cmd):
    global result
    # something goes here
    result = whatever it shall be.
```

Or parameterize it:

```
def job(cmd, result):
    result = whatever it shall be.
```

Comment: ...thanks. Any idea why the print statement in job() is returning zero, though?

Comment: It would only do that if `check_output` returns an empty list. Why `check_output` would be doing that I'm not sure.

Comment: After much head banging & hair pulling, I believe I've discovered the root problem. It appears the system command I am calling (Bowtie2) likes to return its output via stderr, not stdout. I am now able to capture its output by using stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, like so: output = subprocess.check_output(cmd.split(),stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)